# error while trying to compile .data() from std::array as a constexpr function in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, stdarray, constexpr-function

I was trying to compute an array in compilation time to speed up some functions while i encountered an error which I was unable to resolve with the help of cppreference.

The code boils down to this:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>

template<typename T, size_t size>
constexpr auto giveArray()
{
    std::array<T, size> arr;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        arr[i] = 0;
    return arr;
}

constexpr auto arr = giveArray<int,10>().data();
```

While compiling with: "$ g++ -std=c++20 code.cpp" on ubuntu i get the error that .data() is not a constexpr function while it definitely is. Why am i getting this error and how it can be fixed while still running this function in compilation time and storing only a pointer, not the std::array object?

Comment: Are you using a recent-enough version of your standard library that makes `data` constexpr? Also, this will still be broken, as the array object no longer exists, so it will be a pointer to a destroyed object.

Comment: Remember that code that runs at compile time that would exhibit Undefined Behavior is required to fail to compile instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux There is actually no undefined behavior in having a pointer to a destroyed temporary (afaik). The UB comes when value is accessed through the pointer. The rule applied here is likely the restriction that constant expressions of pointer type must point to static objects (here, the would-be pointer points to nothing at all).

Comment: The error does not say that `data()` is not a constexpr function. The error (on every version of gcc I've tried) says `'(int*)(&<anonymous>.std::array<int, 10>::_M_elems)' is not a constant expression`. Which is certainly not an ideal compiler error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To initialize a `constexpr` variable you need an initializer that is a constant expression. But `giveArray<int,10>().data();` is not a constant expression.

From [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#12) :

> A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> - if the value is an object of class type, each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression,
> - if the value is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such an object ([expr.add]), the address of a non-immediate function, or a null pointer value,
> - if the value is of pointer-to-member-function type, it does not designate an immediate function, and
> - if the value is an object of class or array type, each subobject satisfies these constraints for the value.
>   An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an object with static storage duration that either is not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or if it is a non-immediate function.

The expression `giveArray<int,10>().data();` has the value category of prvalue , so it is not a glvalue expression. That means it has to be *"a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints"* to be a constant expression. Since the expression evaluates to a pointer type, it has to meet this condition :

> - if the value is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such an object ([expr.add]), the address of a non-immediate function, or a null pointer value

In this case, it is none of those things so it is not a constant expression. However, if you change the code to like :

```
const auto my_array = giveArray<int,10>();
constexpr auto arr = my_array.data();
```

`my_array` is a global variable, which implies it has static storage duration. `data()` returns a pointer to that storage, which makes it a constant expression.

In short, this rule makes it so you can't have a pointer with an invalid pointer value when executing code at compile time.

Comment: is the `constexpr` really needed for `my_array`? isn't global object already in static storage?

Comment: @appleapple You're right that it isn't required. And `constexpr` isn't sufficient in case `my_array` isn't global. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 6):

> storing only a pointer, not the std::array object?

You can't.

The rules of C++ are not suspended just because your code executes at compile time (indeed, *not* suspending those rules is half the point of `constexpr` code). The array needs to exist in order for a pointer to it to be meaningful. That means the array object needs to continue to be around when someone uses that pointer.

Getting a pointer to a temporary that gets destroyed will leave that pointer pointing to a destroyed object. This is just as true in compile-time code as runtime code. And using that pointer is just as non-functional at compile-time as it would be at runtime. Indeed, it's *less* functional, as UB (which is what accessing that pointer will provoke) at compile-time must be diagnosed and turned into a compile error.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
constexpr auto a0 = giveArray<int,10>();
constexpr auto arr = a0.data();
```

I mean... whith

```
constexpr auto arr = giveArray<int,10>().data();
```

you try to initialize `arr` with a pointer to memory that is set free immediately after.

You can solve fixing the `std::array` received from `giveArray()`

```
constexpr auto a0 = giveArray<int,10>();
```

so `arr` receive a pointer to a memory that remain stable after the initialization

```
constexpr auto arr = a0.data();
```